# What is the meaning of this statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

The code below makes sense individually, but i do not get how it all works when it is combined into one statement like shown below.

The line i have trouble understanding is "discard.test(word) || (......" What is the or || operators doing in this statement?

```
words.forEach(function(word) {
        discard.test(word) || (word = word.replace(punctuation, ""),stopWords.test(word.toLowerCase()) || (word = word.substr(0, maxLength), tag_index[word.toLowerCase()] = word, tags[word = word.toLowerCase()] = (tags[word] || 0) + 1));
    });
```

Comment: It is a `logical or` operator. Basically it will conditionally apply the left value, if its a fasley value it will instead apply the right. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), however using so many in a single condition is really bad practice. There used allot for default options to apply the default should the user not provide a value etc.

Comment: Has this come from a minifier (I hope so... that looks a maintenance nightmare otherwise...), if so you could compare to the original code to glean some clues...

Comment: Yes this code came from a minifier. I never knew you could append statements with || and keep going to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is this, a bit rectified.

```
words.forEach(function(word) {
    if (!discard.test(word)) {
        word = word.replace(punctuation, "");
        if (!stopWords.test(word.toLowerCase()) {
            word = word.substr(0, maxLength);
            tag_index[word.toLowerCase()] = word;
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            tags[word] = (tags[word] || 0) + 1);
        }
    }
});
```

It's a short writing for

```
if (!condition) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the code you provided makes perfect sense

Comment: There is also a comma operator: `word = word.replace(punctuation, ""),stopWords.test(word.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 2):

The code after the `||` will only execute if `discard.test(word)` returns something falsy.

Comment: Ok so you can keep adding || and appending sentences to the right?